# After Symfony-Update: Call to a member function has() on null on /login

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

Until yesterday, my symfony application works fine. It was `Symfony 2.8.32`, Userbundle Version dev-master.

3 Weeks ago, I make a composer update - all works still fine.

Today I do the same, the Symfony version is now `2.8.33`, and now on trying login I get:

> Call to a member function has() on null in 
>   vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php
>   at line 18

The code at this point is:

```
  if ($this->container->has('templating')) {
            return $this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse($view, $parameters, $response);
        }
```

It seems, something in Userbundle isn't changing, and `$this->container` is null.

I have tried a downgrade on `Symfony 2.8.32`, but that does not help.

Any idea?

Comment: Probably a dup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48153155/vendor-updates-crashed-fos-security/48153595#48153595

Comment: Yes - that solution has solved the problem! Thanks! Version for friendsofsymfony/user-bundle is now  "~2.0"

Answer (score 1):

Ok, problem is solved: Write in composer.json:

"friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0",

instead of "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "~2.0@dev",