# FOS User Bundle breaks down Symfony app without debug mode

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, symfony-2.8

I'm using:

- symfony/symfony: v2.8.34
- friendsofsymfony/user-bundle: v2.0.2

So when I start my app like `$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);` the app crushes.

And I get:

```
[2018-02-22 15:40:45] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: "Call to a member function has() on null" at /var/www/html/Brokers/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php line 375 {"exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Call to a member function has() on null at /var/www/html/Brokers/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php:375)"} []
```

With `$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);` everything works fine.

P.S.
I also did this [Vendor updates broke FOS User Bundle with "Call to a member function has() on a non-object"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48153155/vendor-updates-broke-fos-user-bundle-with-call-to-a-member-function-has-on-a)

Comment: Might need a bit more info.  With a fresh install of 2.8.24/2.0.2 the out of the box welcome screen works.  Did you configure the fos user bundle?  Is this an existing app that you are trying to upgrade?  The error message comes from the older 1.3 style of making controllers.

Comment: On my minimal installation, register login logout all seem to work fine in production.  Needless to say, but I'll say it anyways, make sure your delete and then rebuild the production cache.